# Derivation of Bondi metric

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, gravitational-waves

I was trying to understand the BMS formalism from the beginning. The whole formalism depends on the expression of the Bondi metric. I don't understand how this expression of the metric was derived. Even in the first paper by Bondi (1960), its derivation has not been given. Is there a way to derive it?

This is the reference article.

https://doi.org/10.4249/scholarpedia.33528

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easy way to answer your question is to say that in $D$ dimensions there are $D$ coordinate choices to be made and the Bondi metric has $D$ gauge conditions
$$
g_{rr} = 0 , \qquad g_{ra} = 0 , \qquad \partial_r \det ( r^{-2} g_{ab} ) = 0 ,
$$
where $a=1,\cdots,D-2$. Therefore, one can always bring *any* metric into Bondi form.

To be honest, the above answer is sufficient. However, I'm guessing that what you're really looking for is the physical meaning behind the coordinates $u$, $r$ and $x^a$ so lets do that as well.

---

Let $(M,g)$ be a Lorentzian $D$ dimensional spacetime. Let $x^\mu$ be generalized coordinates on a local region of $M$.

We foliate this spacetime by a family null hypersurfaces $\Gamma_c$ described by $u(x) = c$. $u(x)$ is defined such that it increases towards the future. The outward-pointing null normal on this family of surfaces is
$$
n_\mu = -  \partial_\mu u , \qquad n^\mu n_\mu = 0 .  \tag{1}
$$
Each of null hypersurfaces $\Gamma_c$ are generated by null geodesics and $n^\mu$ is the tangent vector to these null geodesics. Let the coordinates $x^a$ label the null generators (i.e. $x^a$ is fixed along any given null geodesic). Further, let $r$ be a parameter along these null geodesics such that
$$
n^\mu = e^{-2\beta} \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial r} . \tag{2}
$$
Until this point, the definitions were completely general and are applicable in any spacetime. Note that $r$ is an arbitrary choice of parameterization so we can choose it however we want. For instance, one convenient choice might be to set $\beta = 0$ since in that case $r$ would the affine parameter along the geodesics. This choice was made by Newman and Unti when they studied the BMS group (see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.0589.pdf)). More generally, the affine parameter is defined by
$$
d\lambda = e^{2\beta} d r.
$$

BMS made a different choice which made reference to the fact that the spacetime is asymptotically flat as follows. We note that expansion of the null geodesics is given by
$$
\theta = \nabla_\mu n^\mu = \frac{d}{d\lambda} \log A .
$$
$\theta$ captures the change of the area $A$ of the transverse section of $\Gamma_u$ as a function of the affine parameter $\lambda$.

Now, in flat spacetime the transverse section $\Gamma_u$ is simply a sphere of radius $r$, so its area is
$$
A = C r^{D-2}
$$
The affine parameter along the null geodesics is $r$ so
$$
\theta = \frac{D-2}{r}.
$$
BMS made a coordinate choice that generalizes the equation above to more general metrics,
$$
\theta = e^{-2\beta} \frac{D-2}{r} . \tag{3} 
$$

---

We are now ready to write down the metric in Bondi coordinates $x^\mu = (u,r,x^a)$. In this coordinate system, equations (1) and (2) read
$$
n_\mu = ( - 1 , 0 , 0_a ) , \qquad n^\mu = ( 0 , e^{-2\beta}  , 0 , 0^a ) . 
$$
However, we have
$$
n^\mu = g^{\mu\nu} n_\nu \implies (0,1,0,0^a) = ( -  g^{uu} , -  g^{ur} , -  g^{ua} ) 
$$
It follows that $g^{uu} = 0$, $g^{ur} = e^{-2\beta}$ and $g^{ua} = 0$. We define $g^{rr} = U$ and $g^{ra} = U^a$ so the inverse metric in these coordinates takes the form
$$
g^{\mu\nu} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & - e^{-2\beta} & 0^b \\ - e^{-2\beta} & U & U^b \\ 0^a & U^a & g^{ab} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Inverting this metric, we find that the line element is
$$
ds^2 = - U du^2 - 2 e^{2\beta} du dr  + g_{ab} ( dx^a + U^a du ) ( dx^b + U^b du ) . 
$$
This is Bondi form of the metric.

Finally, we must also simplify equation (3) in these coordinates. First, we note the property
$$
\det(g_{\mu\nu}) =  e^{2\beta} \det (g_{ab} ) . 
$$
Then,
\begin{align}
\theta &= \nabla_\mu n^\mu \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{ - \det(g_{\mu\nu})}} \partial_\mu \left( \sqrt{ - \det(g_{\mu\nu})} n^\mu \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} e^{-2\beta}  \partial_r \log \det(g_{ab})
\end{align}
Equation (3) then implies
$$
\frac{1}{2} \partial_r \log \det(g_{ab}) = \frac{D-2}{r}  \implies \partial_r \det ( r^{-2} g_{ab} ) = 0. 
$$